# tailwind horizontal line on right and left side of a div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a line on the right side and left side of the test div/border, but cannot figure out a way how to do it. There are not any sorurces online and thought someone might know how to.

The drawn yellow lines are supposed to be the lines.

[image: img]

```html
<!-- Tailwind -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="grid grid-cols-12 mb-20">
  <div class="col-span-5 text-right">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-span-2 mx-auto mt-10">
    <div class="sm:block w-0.5 bg-black absolute h-full left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-span-5 pr-1">
    <div class="border rounded-full bg-black border-white border-4 w-8 h-8 absolute left-1/2 -translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 transform -translate-x-1/2 flex items-center justify-center mt-10"></div>

    <div class="border-2 border-black p-4 lg:p-4 lg:max-w-md">
      <p class="text-2xl text-center font-extrabold lg:text-6xl ">test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in the following way, now the positioning I guess you can manage i.e. how much away from center you want or so.

```html
<!-- Tailwind -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Body -->
<div className="grid grid-cols-12 mb-20">
  <div className="col-span-5 text-right">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div className="col-span-1 mt-10">
    <div className="sm:block w-0.5 bg-black absolute h-full left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2"></div>
  </div>

  <div className="col-span-6">
    <div className="border rounded-full bg-black border-white border-4 w-8 h-8 absolute left-1/2 -translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 transform -translate-x-1/2 flex items-center justify-center mt-10"></div>
    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 items-center mt-6">
      <div>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div className="text-center font-extrabold  border-2 border-black p-4">test</div>
      <div>
        <hr />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use a working [repro] (`Ctrl+M` or `<>`) including Tailwind CSS to show your solution?

Comment: it doesn't work due to the space. The HR tags are not connected

Comment: @ClaytonCrockville I couldn't get your point.

Comment: there's spacing left when I add <hr> tag on col-span-1, it doesn't touch the black dot

Comment: @ClaytonCrockville I have edited the code, maybe now it will run, there might be issue of media queries but it's working on lg so you can make further changes for md and sm devices too